# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Scalar UDF results in infinite loop

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pattern-matching, user-defined-functions

The following code is resulting in an infinite loop or really really slow execution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CleanUriPart] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @DirtyUriPart nvarchar(200)
)

RETURNS nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN;
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result nvarchar(200);

DECLARE @i int;

SET @i = 1;

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN;
    SET @i = PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]%', @DirtyUriPart COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN);
    IF @i > 0
        SET @DirtyUriPart = STUFF(@DirtyUriPart, @i, 1, '-');
    ELSE
        BREAK;
END;

-- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
SELECT @Result = @DirtyUriPart;

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @Result;

END;
```

The input/output should be as follows:

- 'abcdef' -> 'abcdef' works ok
- 'abc-def' -> 'abc-def' results in infinite loop
- 'abc*def' -> 'abc-def' results in infinite loop
- etc.

Please help!

Comment: You never change `@DirtyUriPart` inside the loop so the value of `@i` will never change on subsequent iterations.

Comment: No that was me panicking and messing with my code. It still results in an infinite loop.

Comment: Looks like the pattern might need to be changed to `'%[^-a-zA-Z0-9.~_]%'` actually. I'm assuming that it is treating that `-` as being part of a range syntax even though it has no RHS.

Comment: Ahhhhhh that was scary. This is why I try to avoid stuff I don't understand. Thanks for your help. What does RHS mean?

Comment: "Right Hand Side". I can't find any documentation that says how the `-` symbol without both a LHS and RHS is treated though so will need to do some testing to confirm this.

Comment: But with `'%[^-a-zA-Z0-9.~_]%'` it has an RHS and no LHS?

Comment: `SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]%', N'abc-def' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN), PATINDEX('%[^-a-zA-Z0-9.~_]%', N'abc-def' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)` return different results so moving the `-` has had some sort of effect. Note that without the `N` prefix both return the same so the difference only applies to Unicode. Need to do some more investigation!

Comment: I plan on using this function on NVARCHAR columns so do I need to worry about this? NVARCHAR is unicode basically?

Comment: The BOL example for `[-acdf]` indicates that moving the `-` character to the beginning as per my earlier comment is indeed the correct solution to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-]%', N'aaa-def' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN),
       PATINDEX('%[^-a]%', N'aaa-def' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN), 
       PATINDEX('%[^a-]%', 'aaa-def' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN),
       PATINDEX('%[^-a]%', 'aaa-def' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)
```

Returns

```
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           5           5           5
```

So it seems that for `varchar` datatypes a trailing `-` is treated as being part of a set whereas for `nvarchar` it is ignored (treated as a malformed range as `a` is ignored too?)

The BOL entry for [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) doesn't explicitly talk about how to use `-` within `[]` to get it to be treated as part of a set but does have the example

```
LIKE '[-acdf]'
```

to match `-, a, c, d, or f` so I assume that it needs to be the first item in a set (i.e. that `[^a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]` needs to be altered to `[^-a-zA-Z0-9.~_]`). That also matches the result of my testing above.

Comment: You had me worried when you said that `SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]%', N'abc-def' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN), PATINDEX('%[^-a-zA-Z0-9.~_]%', N'abc-def' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)` return different results! They do return different results, one correct and one incorrect... So yeah `%[^-a-zA-Z0-9.~_]%'` seems to work fine. Thanks again - I've learnt quite a lot for a Sunday!

Comment: Is this a bug in SQL Server 2008 then?

Comment: @ChrisCannon - Not sure RE: Bug. I can't see the difference in behaviour between `varchar` vs `nvarchar` documented anywhere and definitely not intuitive that there should be any difference there.

Comment: Reproduces on SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2012. So if it's a bug, it's one that has escaped detection for a long time.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - [Response to my Connect Item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/742841/pattern-syntax-undocumented-difference-in-behaviour-between-varchar-vs-nvarchar#tabs)

Answer (score 1):

Any chance @DirtyUriPart can evaluate to NULL? ON the PATINDEX function, if either pattern or expression is NULL, PATINDEX returns NULL and a NULL in this case will cause a infinite loop

Comment: I'll add a check for IS NULL to the IF clause to ensure it breaks where @i IS NULL. The problem is was with the PATINDEX pattern. Could you provide me with some tips on that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could fix the problem by casting `@DirtyUriPart` as `VARCHAR(200)` in `PATINDEX`, which will cause the dash to be recognized along with the other characters in the class:

```
DECLARE @DirtyUriPart nvarchar(200)='abc-def';

-- Returns 0
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]%', CAST(@DirtyUriPart AS VARCHAR(200)) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN);

-- Returns 4
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]%', @DirtyUriPart COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN);
```